# Tortoise SVN Command Problem

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, diff

I am trying to use the Tortoise SVN command line utility TortoiseProc.exe. The docs suggest that a command line like this:

```
"TortoiseProc.exe" /command:diff afile.cpp`
```

should do a diff and display the results in the configured diff viewer (in my case Tortoise's own one), but instead nothing happens - the viewer is not launched & no error messages appear.

If I do:

```
svn diff afile.cpp
```

from the same directory, I get the normal Subversion diff text output.

Paths are OK, Tortoise works fine from the context menu, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `/path:` before the name of your source file:

```
"TortoiseProc.exe" /command:diff /path:afile.cpp
```

Tested on my TortoiseSVN.

See http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html

Comment: I defer to those who type faster.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link, completely unrelated problem that got solved by a little reading.